# 400 error for profile image -- every other time, every time

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook graph profile image unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183000/facebook-graph-profile-image-unreliable)

I am having a bizarre issue which is most likely the same as this post on the developer forum:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108447

Every other time I load the page it will issue the 400 [Bad Request] error, and every *other* time it will load the image successfully. This cycle is consistent.

I am directly accessing the graph URL, without any middleware e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/1063500095/picture?type=large`

I am worried it is a problem on Facebook's side because this just started happening yesterday. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For me it's a similar problem, I got round it by displaying less images then I was doing (I was trying to request 20+ images at once), now I'm only requesting say 5. Seemed to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the image as you are supposed to.  Log a [bug with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) (not that you will likely get a response) for any issues.

Comment: Posted here:http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20001