# Facebook graph profile image unreliable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to display a comments feed on my Facebook application, I am loading in an array of Facebook user ids and an associated comment, to display the users profile picture, I am using the following snippet:

```
<?php echo '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$c->_user.'/picture'" />; ?>
```

This works fine, and gets the image, however, if I refresh my page, I get some if not all of the thumbnails will not be loaded, refresh again and they'll always be there, it's pretty consistent that when I refresh they'll appear, next time they won't and so on.

Should I be dealing with this differently ? I know that in the browser the graph API redirects to the actual image, so maybe this is what's causing my browser to sometimes not display them, say if, it took too long to load the image ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [400 error for profile image -- every other time, every time](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7182954/400-error-for-profile-image-every-other-time-every-time)

Comment: Thank you this does seem very similar - I reduced the amount of pictures I was trying to display at once and it seemed to let me off the hook, I guess I was requesting too many things from Facebook at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably what [genesis φ says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183000/facebook-graph-profile-image-unreliable/7183023#7183023) says, just a temporary issue on Facebook's end. But to add on to his suggestions, you might try serving the image from `https:`. Alternatively, you can get the full, redirect-less picture URL from the [`user` FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try https, I was actually originally using that, I think using the FQL table will really hinder my apps performance. Thanks for the suggestion I was unaware the direct url was in there.

Comment: @Daniel Probably true, just wanted to toss the idea out there. You can get that same URL by following the `HTTP 302` redirects from the graph URL, and you could cache that for a limited amount of time (I don't know how long it takes and if those URLS expire) and serve that directly. Of course, that's assuming the problem is in the redirect, which it may well not be.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just their temporary issue. If you want to be sure, download them for the first time and you could "host" them more reliabily

Comment: Sure maybe it's their issue, but what's really curious is the fact it displays once then on next refresh fails to load, but guaranteed to load on next refresh and so on...

Comment: @Daniel you could try to look into Firebug or into other developer tools and look for responses

Comment: @Daniel: I've got no problem with loading here http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/4f65b/1

Comment: Your same works great, maybe I'm trying to request too many pictures at once, as I am using php to put together the markup and I'm requesting at this stage 11 different images multiple times.