# Libgdx getting Image from facebook at runtime

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, libgdx

I have image-url getting from facebook, I want to display that image at runtine in my game in libgdx.I am using facebook graph api and parse data with help of Json parsing. my approach is as follows:

In main activity

```
protected void gettingfacebookData() {
    try {
        JSONArray friendArray = new JSONArray(
                prefLevel.getFriendFacebookData());
        for (int i = 0; i < friendArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = friendArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String score = jsonObject.getString("score");
            String fid = jsonObject.getString("fid");
            String image = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fid
                    + "/picture?type=large";
//saving score into array list
            PlayingScreen.scoreAl.add(score);
//saving image url into arraylist
            PlayingScreen.imageUrlAl.add(image);

            }           }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now how can I display image at run time with this particular image url?

Answer (score 3):

We use a wrapper class, that wraps `Texture`, for displaying images from web (like facebook profile pictures). This wrapper class takes url of the image and a temporary texture. Just as the wrapper is created, it starts to download image bytes in a background thread. Consumer of this wrapper class simply calls `getTexture()` to obtain texture and until download has finished, this method returns the temporary texture. When there are bytes available to create a texture `getTexture()` processes this bytes and starts to return new texture created from url.

Below is a simple version of this wrapper class. Note that, `processTextureBytes` is called inside `getTexture` method, not somewhere in background thread. It is because we have to construct texture in the thread which obtains the GLContext. You can add caching and retry mechanisms to this class.

BTW, instead of using `http://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/picture` url try using one of `pic_` urls from [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/). You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183261/554397).

```
public class WebTexture {
    private final String url;
    private Texture texture;
    private volatile byte[] textureBytes;

    public WebTexture(String url, Texture tempTexture) {
        this.url = url;
        texture = tempTexture;
        downloadTextureAsync();
    }

    private void downloadTextureAsync() {
        Utils.runInBackground(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textureBytes = downloadTextureBytes();
            }
        });
    }

    private byte[] downloadTextureBytes() {
        try {
            return Utils.downloadData(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        if (textureBytes != null)
            processTextureBytes();
        return texture;
    }

    private void processTextureBytes() {
        try {
            Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(textureBytes, 0, textureBytes.length);
            Texture gdxTexture = new Texture(pixmap);
            gdxTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
            texture = gdxTexture;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            textureBytes = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the import for Utils?

Comment: yeah, what is that that import?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should download the image.
2. Once you have your image as a byte array, you can create a pixmap:

   `Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);`
3. Then you can use this pixmap to render the image. For example if are you using scene2d.ui you can set Image's drawable as follows:

`image.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(profilePicture))));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is actually I am doing right now but i get error of progressive jpeg image error and at that time my game is start lagging, because I am only saving the url not downloaded image and start image downloading at run time which cause lagging :(

Comment: Are you getting progressive jpeg error on desktop or on android?