# Detecting and dealing with 400 errors inside img tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am developing an app that embeds users' Facebook profile picture(http://graph.facebook.com/(fb id)/picture) inside an img tag.  And it works...for the most part.  However I will occasionally get 400 errors when I request the profile picture([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182954/400-error-for-profile-image-every-other-time-every-time))

Is there any way I can detect these 400 errors with Javascript/JQuery?  Right now they are being displayed as a broken image....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple using the `onerror` event.

We can simply create a new image in JavaScript and attach two events to it - `onload` and `onerror`. Then setting the image `src` will make the browser download the image, firing the `onload` event if it is a true image, or `onerror` if not.

```
var img = new Image();

// This URL will return an image an fire `onload`
img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/300/300';

// Replace the line above with this one to load a fake/unavailable image, which will fire the `onerror` event.
// img.src = 'http://mybrokenurl';

img.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

img.onerror = function() {
    alert('Error loading image');
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/vSJ4F/